# How do you do a generic insert with JDBI?

Tags: java, mysql, generics, jdbi

I am using JDBI with MySQL and I've an interface GenericDao where I've this method

```
public void insert(T entity);
```

How do I implement this method with JDBI by using the fluent queries instead of SQLObjects?

Is it possible to use either of this?

```
handle.insert
```

or

```
handle.createQuery
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that SQLObjects worked nice for me when I used SQLObjects style:

```
public interface GenericDao<T> {
    List<T> findAll();
    long insert(T t);
    long update(T t);
    long delete(long id);
    T findNameById(long id);
}
```

I then used an abstract class for putting in all the SQL

```
@RegisterMapper(VesselJDBIMapper.class)
public abstract class VesselJDBI implements Transactional<VesselJDBI>, GenericDao<Vessel> {

    @SqlUpdate("UPDATE vessel SET vessel_name = :vesselName, version = version +1 WHERE vessel_id = :id" +
            " AND version = :version")
    public abstract long update(@BindBean Vessel vessel);

    @SqlUpdate("DELETE FROM vessel WHERE vessel_id = :id")
    public abstract long delete(@Bind("id") long id);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT vessel_id, vessel_name, version FROM vessel WHERE vessel_id = :id")
    public abstract Vessel findNameById(@Bind("id") long id);

    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO vessel (vessel_name, version) VALUES (:vesselName, :version)")
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    public abstract long insert(@BindBean Vessel vessel);

    @SqlQuery("SELECT vessel_id, vessel_name, version FROM vessel ORDER BY vessel_id")
    public abstract List<Vessel> findAll();
}
```

Maybe that will provide a solution for someone.

Comment: +1 for `@BindBean`, the most generic binder there is. For completeness, you could put a snippet of your Vessel class up for showing how the SQL placeholders bind to fields.

Comment: this would only be a plain old java object in the example above. In my local codebase I use a more elaborate example that uses Lombok http://projectlombok.org/ to save writing code. If you would like to know more please post a new question and drop me a line or contact me (please have look at my profile). I don't want to add content to this post that is not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get handle by implementing GetHandle interface.

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T>  implements GetHandle {

    public void insert(T entity) {
        getHandle().insert("some sql");
    };

}
```

Comment: How do I map the attributes? Because the entity the generic.

Comment: You can make all the entities to extend/implement some generic abstract class or interface which can give attributes. But if you want to do all this stuff, you can go for some ORM.

Comment: Yeah I chose to go with an ORM